# Load-Bearing Wall? Parallel to Joists, single story, but has attic supports

Tags: structural, load-bearing, beam, engineering, load

I've had multiple professionals look at this wall, and no one has been able to give me a clear answer (2 home inspectors, and 1 structural engineer). So I've come to the source of all truth, the Internet.

The diagram of what's happening ***appears*** to be simple, but as a not-structural-engineer, I can't tell where the load from the roof downward is being applied. Obviously, my long-term game plan here is to remove the wall.

See below - assume that the joists/rafters/collar ties continue regularly: (please let me know if there's more I can diagram)

[image]

The question(s):

1. **Is the wall in question load-bearing?**
2. If it **is** load-bearing, how do I go about calculating the lineal per foot load (e.g. *"what size beam do I need for a 13' span"*)? I have precise measurements available & dead/live psf loads, but because the structural load seems difficult in this case I'm having a lot of trouble determining what size beam would be required for the expected load & span.

Please let me know what additional info I can provide - I have measurements & photos I can reference.

**-Update (Post Work)-**

To close the loop here, the wall was just standard 16" spaced studs (as expected). Shear stress was a potential factor, so a beam was used, though it was not necessary. The wall was not structurally load-bearing, but standard precautions were taken.

Comment: Was there an addition done to the house?

Comment: What are you expecting us to say? If local experts can't tell you it's because the secret is hidden behind drywall. You won't get any confident answers through the tubes between you and us.

Comment: @isherwood - I'm not sure really - I have tools that appear to confirm that the construction behind the drywall is exactly as anticipated. For the sake of future askers, can we just assume that it's a double top plate with regular studs? If so, does that mean it's load-bearing?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - no, the front room always existed, but it was converted to a living room shortly after original construction (1980). I suspect the only reason the wall is there in the first place was because it was a divider/firewall between the old garage and the kitchen.

Comment: Walls between living areas and garages do have special requirements, and that could also be the reason for the "supports" in the attic.  But if your "structural engineer" didn't point those things out you should probably find a better one.  You need someone more qualified than a home inspector but a proper engineer should be able to work this out.

Comment: All walls will have standard stud layouts and double plates. We don't use two different stud lengths when building homes. You can't tell anything from those features.

Comment: @isherwood - OK, understood - if that's the case then, what is *not* known about the construction here (i.e. what more can I provide)?

Comment: What you have labeled "supports" is a _gable truss_. As JPhi1618 pointed out, it's because a firewall is required there. It'll have a 2x4 on edge along the bottom and vertical 2x members every 24". It's usually identical to the actual gable end trusses.

Comment: What's not known is whether there are any interior bearing points in the truss, beams being carried by the wall, or footings below it. It's a fairly safe assumption that it's not load-bearing, but as I said, we can't be more than 90% sure from here. If you want certainty, we ain't it. :)

Comment: @isherwood - Thanks, & just to check my thinking on this - assuming there were no additional bearing points in the truss (it really looks exactly like the diagram), no add'l beams, standard wall framing (double-plate + studs), & no footings (slab foundation), then the wall should generally not be load-bearing, right? (I know this is not a 100% thing, just trying to check my reasoning - also would have to potentially account for supporting the truss itself)

Comment: Or I suppose, @Michael-Karas , if you have any thoughts on the same question

Comment: Excellent work with the update/edit, thank you for closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your front section at one time was a garage the there was a need to provide a fire break wall between the garage and the living portion of the house. Since the garage undoubtedly had an open ceiling all the way up into the rafter area the fire break wall had to extend way  up to the roof line. To support the heavy drywall used as sheathing on the fire break wall studding was added from the top plate of the lower wall up to the rafters.

The drywall used on such walls is often 5/8" thick or two layers of 1/2" thick material.

If going by your picture is accurate it is doubtful if this is a load bearing wall in the conventional sense. However depending on the construction of the top plate it may not be providing the necessary strong tie behavior to prevent rafter sagging in that area if the lower wall was to be removed.

Comment: Agreed, inasmuch as guesses do the OP any real good.

Comment: And you make a good point about the gable truss possibly not being self-supporting. It shouldn't be expected to span any significant distance without a header under it or suitable  shear bracing on its face.

Comment: @Michael Karas - Fantastic, this was sort-of my assessment initially as well, but the analysis of the vertical supports is new & helpful. Originally I then second-guessed myself and decided "pretend it's load-bearing" but was having heaps of trouble determining total load. I believe the top plate is well-constructed & well-placed on 2 jack(king?) studs based on checks in the drywall. I will still have another structural engineer take a look just in case, & will also plan to support underneath even if it shouldn't have load.